# Trying to make Open CV python work on Anaconda Jupyter

Tags: python, opencv

> Installing OpenCV from prebuilt binaries
>
> ```
> Below Python packages are to be downloaded and installed to their default locations.
>
> Python-2.7.x.
>
> Numpy.
>
> Matplotlib (Matplotlib is optional, but recommended since we use it a lot in our tutorials).
>
> Install all packages into their default locations. Python will be installed to C:/Python27/.
>
> After installation, open Python IDLE. Enter import numpy and make sure Numpy is working fine.
>
> Download latest OpenCV release from sourceforge site and double-click to extract it.
>
> Goto opencv/build/python/2.7 folder.
>
> Copy cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packages.
>
> Open Python IDLE and type following codes in Python terminal.
> ```
>
> > > > import cv2
> > > >         print cv2.**version** If the results are printed out without any errors, congratulations !!! You have installed OpenCV-Python
> > > >         successfully.

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <modul
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I am trying to get tesseract and opencv up and running for past 2 days.I had uninstall python 3 and almost everything related to it as most of the modules ran in python 2.7 .Still after reverting back python 2.7 and reinstalling everything still its showing No module named cv2.Am at my wits end .Please help me

Comment: Do you have any errors on install? Try install [from wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python): `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: @9dogs bro I am about to try .Currently the download of the package is going on I tried installing from anaconda archives its taking too much time installation going on at 64k/bs second if that also does not work .I will try yours and get back to you.Right now I had copied the cv2.pyd to the site-packages folder and yet after trying do import module not found error is shown